# Python, Streamlit - null dataframe

Tags: python, streamlit

In my code i filter some data in dataframe:

```
CurrentBOM = merged_Plan_BOM_df.loc[(merged_Plan_BOM_df['ORDER_REF_STR'] == filtered_df['ORDER_REF_STR'].item())]
```

I am looking for one item which i want to visualisate like below:

```
with st.container():
    col2.dataframe(CurrentBOM,100,1000)
```

It is working properly, but what with the situataion when the CurrentBOM is empty(no results in this moment). I have an error.

I want to understand how manage my "queries" on dataframe when they are null.

Comment: Post the error message.

Comment: Is it not possible to assign null value when is null? Then i can show "nothing" in container.
do I really need to use Try and catch for each variables? Thank you so much